# How to set focus and display keyboard in safari with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to set focus and place the cursor in a text box and bring up the keyboard automatically when I pop up a modal dialog. I don't want the user to click anywhere.  This works fine everywhere except on mobile Safari.

I tried focus(), touchstart, timeouts, direct and indirect event generation, etc. with jQuery with no luck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a click event after setting the focus

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it. The text box does get focus, but the keyboard doesn't get displayed.  I'm using the following code: `setTimeout(function () { $('textbox').focus().click(); }, 1000); ` .  Am I missing anything? Have you been able to do this?

Comment: Don’t chain focus call and click: 2 instructions